# Build a debian package with user settings

Tags: pyqt, debian, config, packaging

I'm packaging a PyQt application for Linux as a `.deb` package, following [the Debian maintenance guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/start.en.html).
The manual does a good job describing how to build the python binaries with `debuild -b`, and install global data files in `/usr/share/<package>/` through the `debian/install` file. However, I don't see any mention of installing user settings files - cache files or files for configuration changes that the current user running the program might want to save.
As far as I understand, other programs usually save these in a hidden directory on the users home path - eg atom's user data in `/home/<username>/.atom/`.

The manual does mention [conffiles](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#conffiles). However these seem to be globally installed. I'm also not sure if they're suitable for config files that change frequently as a result of user actions, since package updates will attempt to solve conflicts between new and existing conffiles.

Some other documentation mentions postinstall scripts, but this seems potentially too complicated for something that should be common to many debian packages?